# Google app script return undefined before user gives answer yes/no on dialog

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The method return is undefined before user clicks yes/no. According to Google app script, server process should be frozen when dialog shows up. But in my test, the value is returned before users clicks yes/no.

```
function getValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var okToInsert = true;
  if (sheet.getName() !== "xxx") {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var alert = ui.alert('Confirm',
        'Your active sheet is not "xxx". Continue to insert?',
        ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if(alert == ui.Button.NO){
      okToInsert = false;
    }
  }

  return {
     "okToInsert": okToInsert
  };
}
```

This is my frontend js:

```
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(
      function(selectedRange, scope) {
        console.log(">>> selectedRange: " + selectedRange);
      })
    .withFailureHandler(
      function(msg, scope) {
      })
    .withUserObject($scope)
    .getValues();
```

This is how I enable the sidebar:

```
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('sidebar').evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('this is title');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
```

I have a sample sidebar add-on called "Dialog return test" created here.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eHwjHKuBIDw2WOTRU5CZAu9m9V-9mXimFyMlGXbPl-U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs perfectly for me:

[image]

I get the dialogue prompt and return is defined with no errors. It's likely the issue is with another part of your code, or possibly the script file itself. I would recommend trying it on a new script in a new sheets file and try and narrow the issue down from there.

Comment: For me, the function returns to my front end javascript immediately before I choose Yes or No. That's why I got undefined value.

Comment: That seems unlikely to be an issue with the code you've posted, and more a general issue with the code you've written. The description of the function (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String,ButtonSet)) specifies specifically that server side Javascript is suspended until a selection is made, and the code you've posted runs perfectly, so your issue is elsewhere in your script.

Comment: How did you call this function? Did you call it from app script or frontend js? I am calling from frontend js. I tried to do it in the clean environment, but the result is the same.

Comment: From Apps script in a new script with a spreadsheet. If you're experiencing this issue when running it from Frontend JS, and not when you run the code standalone (as it works perfectly for me above), then I stand by what I said earlier, the issue must be elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Can you post your 'doGet' function also? I'm curious to see if you're running it in iFrame/Native/Emulated and some other questions.

Comment: I don't have doGet function in Code.js or frontend js.

Comment: I just add the createTemplateFromFile if this is what you are asking for.

Comment: This means you're using the HTML service, I believe (Possibly as a spreadsheet sidebar?) As I said above, the code you posted works without issue, so I would look there for your issue, but it's unlikely we'll be able to assist further until you narrow the issue down more to a specific piece of code.

Comment: I created a sample add-on to test this problem. Click Adds-on > Dialog return test to see the demo. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eHwjHKuBIDw2WOTRU5CZAu9m9V-9mXimFyMlGXbPl-U/edit?usp=sharing